# Grouping query results in T-SQL by MONTH

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I´m looking for a hint how **to group** my query results by MONTH and WindowsAccount, where the month information comes from the InsertedAt column in the query. I´ll be thankful, if somebody could mention a way how to achieve that. 
Thanking you in advance.

```
 SELECT InsertedAt,
       TaskName,
       WindowsAccount,
       Start,
       Round (Time / 60.1, 2) AS Time
FROM   (SELECT CONVERT (VARCHAR(23), InsertedAt, 104) AS InsertedAt,
               Subject,
               TaskName,
               WindowsAccount,
               CONVERT (VARCHAR(23), NewStart, 104)   AS Start,
               Datediff("MINUTE", OldStart, OldEnd)   AS OldDiff,
               Datediff("MINUTE", NewStart, NewEnd)   AS Time
        FROM   History
        WHERE  ( Month(InsertedAt) IN ( 9, 10, 11 )
                 AND Year(InsertedAt) = 2015 )) AS Tab
WHERE  Tab.OldDiff <> Tab.Time
ORDER  BY InsertedAt,
          WindowsAccount
```

Comment: If you have two records with InsertedAt values 2015-11-09 and 2015-11-06 (same month), then which value you want to see in results? Same problem with Start and Time fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can group using the DatePart function.

As an Example (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177673.aspx):

```
SELECT DATEPART(m,OrderDate) AS N'Month'
    ,SUM(TotalDue) AS N'Total Order Amount'
FROM Sales.SalesOrderHeader
GROUP BY DATEPART(m,OrderDate)
ORDER BY DATEPART(m,OrderDate);
```

Comment: Thank you, @momar
My goal is to preserve the following columns for the output without adding new ones. Only these columns are required for my report. InsertedAt, TaskName, WindowsAccount, Start and Time. InsertedAt is a standard date column. Is it possible from your perspective to group by month and WindowsAccount based on my criteria? How would be the query look like? Thank you!

Comment: @IvanaMaria Using group by means you have to use aggregate functions  (Sum, Count, etc.) on the other columns. It might be better to put some sample data and the expected result to get a better understanding of what you want to achieve with the query

Comment: Thanks @momar. 
My query aims to deliver information from a DB where the results should come from the last 3 months of this year (column 'InsertedAt') and show results that match the criteria OldDiff<>Time. The output columns are limited to there (InsertedAt, TaskName, WindowsAccount, Start and Time) and the result should be grouped by month and column WindowsAccount. Maybe my query should look differently in order to be able to group by month?

Comment: With some external help I could solve it my question by adding a column 'months' in the first and second select clause plus adding a SUM function in front of my Round: 'SUM (Round (Time / 60.1, 2)) AS Time'. Then the grouping was possible.